# Copying a table row and replacing the table tags

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Java Script and really have only experience with C++. I have been looking for an answer to the below question all over and have come up short. Any assistance anyone might be willing to give would be most appreciated.

I am trying to write a JavaScript that at the click of a button will copy a table row and remove the TR /TR tags and replace it with a P /P and then store that into a variable that i can either create a new format that is copy and paste friendly with no table cells or copy that information to clipboard which i can easily paste into word. At present i have been able to clone the table row but cannot parse out the data between the tags and remove the table formatting and add the paragraph formatting.

Thank you.

Here is a small demo program that completes the first step of what i want to do. You will notice if you check the boxes of the sections and click truncate the boxes not checked will disappear. What i need to do now is copy the text within those checked boxes(but only the text and have each become a paragraph) to either the clipboard or have them parsed and printed in a word copy and paste friendly format.

**Script:**

```
  var section0 = 6; //# of Basic Conditions
  function cloneTable() {
    for(var i = 0; i < section0; i++) //Basic Conditions
    {
      if(i == 0 || document.getElementById("check00-" + i).checked) {
        var row = document.getElementById('condition00-' + i); // find row to copy
        var table = document.getElementById("table2"); // find table to append to
        var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
        clone.id = "newID"; // change id or other attributes/contents
        table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
      }
    }
    var elem = document.getElementById('table1')
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
  }
```

**Markup:**

```
<table width=890 style='table-layout:fixed'>
  <col width=20>
    <col width=30>
      <col width=840>
        <tbody id="table1">
          <tr id="condition00-0">
            <td width=20 valign="top">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check00-0">
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left"><font size="6" face="Arial"><a  name="Bookmark1">Header</a></font>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="condition00-1">
            <td valign="top">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check00-1" onclick="MainTitles('check00-0')">
            </td>
            <td valign="top"><font size="4" face="Arial">1.</font>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="word-wrap: break-word"><font size="4" face="Arial">Text section1</font>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="condition00-2">
            <td valign="top">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check00-2" onclick="MainTitles('check00-0')">
            </td>
            <td valign="top"><font size="4" face="Arial">2.</font>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="word-wrap: break-word"><font size="4" face="Arial">Text section 2</font>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="condition00-3">
            <td valign="top">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check00-3" onclick="MainTitles('check00-0')">
            </td>
            <td valign="top"><font size="4" face="Arial">3.</font>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="word-wrap: break-word"><font size="4" face="Arial">Text section 3</font>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="condition00-4">
            <td valign="top">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check00-4" onclick="MainTitles('check00-0')">
            </td>
            <td valign="top"><font size="4" face="Arial">4.</font>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="word-wrap: break-word"><font size="4" face="Arial">Text Section 4</font>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="condition00-5">
            <td valign="top">
              <input type="checkbox" id="check00-5" onclick="MainTitles('check00-0')">
            </td>
            <td valign="top"><font size="4" face="Arial">5.</font>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="word-wrap: break-word"><font size="4" face="Arial">Text Section 5</font>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<table width=890 style='table-layout:fixed'>
  <col width=20>
    <col width=30>
      <col width=840>
        <tbody id="table2"></tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="cloneTable()" value="Truncate" />
```

**JSFiddle:** [Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/9AaXa/3/)

Comment: Would help if you showed some code.

Comment: Is that enough to remove TR tags ? you might need to remove TD tags also. Anyway this might have other solution, show the code

Comment: I have added some code, thank you for help.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for not choosing jQuery?

Comment: Honeslty, i am so new to this i dont even know what JQuery is. I do some robotics and use C++ and told my wife i could try to help her with this document for work. So i tried the first thing i thought i could get to work.

Comment: Oh no need to say sorry. Thank you for taking the time to help me. Once i finish this project I will look into JQuery. Sometimes the hardest part is figureing out what you dont know :) or better yet what are the right questions to ask.

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373043/how-to-dynamically-calculate-the-total-of-each-column-in-a-table-on-an-html-page/15373557#15373557. It demonstrates the techniques you can use to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your rows as DOM elements, loop through each of their cells, and parse the innerHTML to get your value.

See this post: [How to dynamically calculate the total of each column in a table on an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373043/how-to-dynamically-calculate-the-total-of-each-column-in-a-table-on-an-html-page/15373557#15373557)

Example:

```
function strip(html) { // This is a very popular + useful technique.
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
}

var tbl = document.getElementById('my-table');
var rows = tbl.rows;
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   var cells = rows[i].cells;
   for var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
      alert(strip(cells[j].innerHTML));
   }
}
```

Comment: KTM thank you for your response. Is there anyway i could trouble you to comment the code? I do not quite follow what it is doing. Due to my lack of understanding i also do not see how to print/show the information i have stripped from the table.

Comment: KTM, I have been fiddling with the above code but it seems to breaks my truncate functionality.

Comment: Hey Mathieas. I haven't actually tested the code above, but I tested the code in the other post I linked to. I'll reproduce the link here: http://jsfiddle.net/7srJf/3/. You can see how I create a table with two columns, and use JavaScript to loop through the table's DOM structure and get the sum for each column.

Comment: The ideas are simply: (1) use DOM (2) strip the HTML from the innerHTML property (3) use parseInt to get the integer value of a string.